# tc filters not working with DRR

Tags: networking, traffic-shaping, tc, scheduling

I am trying to control the outgoing traffic from two VMs with the DRR qdisc.

This is the hierarchy I want to have:

```
                 root
                  |
              qdisc drr
                 1:
            /     |      \  
           /      |       \
  class drr    class drr     class drr
 quantum 200  quantum 800  (w/ max quantum)
    1:1          1:2            1:3
```

Traffic of VM1 should go to 1:1, traffic of VM2 to 1:2, everything else to 1:3 (as DRR has no default class itself). The outgoing traffic of the VMs gets marked with 1 resp. 2. With `iptables -L -v -n -t mangle` I can see that the packets get correctly marked.

I set this up with the following commands:

```
tc qdisc add dev wlan0 handle 1: root drr
tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1: classid 1:1 drr quantum 200
tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1: classid 1:2 drr quantum 800
tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1: classid 1:3 drr #used as default class
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 handle 1 fw classid 1:1
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 handle 2 fw classid 1:2
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 2 u32 match ip dst 0.0.0.0/0 classid 1:3 #match everything
```

But with this configuration I can't access the network at all. Nearly every packet gets dropped by the root qdisc.

These are the outputs after sending 83 packets from VM1 (all getting marked correctly).

```
#tc -s class show dev wlan0
class drr 1:1 root quantum 200b
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
 deficit 0b
class drr 1:2 root quantum 800b
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
 deficit 0b
class drr 1:3 root quantum 1514b
 Sent 118029 bytes 497 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
 deficit 0b

#tc -s qdisc show dev wlan0
qdisc drr 1: root refcnt 2
 Sent 117057 bytes 493 pkt (dropped 3372, overlimits 0 requeues 0)
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

As you can see, there are no packets getting directed to 1:1 and from the non-VM traffic, only a small part is directed to 1:3.

When using the same filter commands with HTB, everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Since DRR has no default queue, you have to assign arp traffic to a specific queue or these packets will be drop, leading to your machine forgetting its gateway physical address.